# Placing points on right without margin

Tags: margins, exam, points

I'm using the `exam` document class, and have played around with the options for points placement. Essentially, I want something that works like `\pointsdroppedatright`. The only problem is that it creates a margin. I was hoping to avoid the margin altogether, such that the text appears much in the same way using `\hfill` would push it rightwards. I believe this can be done with `qformat`, but I don't know how to do it for parts, subparts, etc.

Here's a minimum working example of what I have now:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\pointsdroppedatright
\marksnotpoints

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        \begin{parts}
            \part[4] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \droppoints
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: What I have at the moment]

Here's what I want:

[image: What I want]

Comment: A Minimal Working Example would help get us started.  I would like to avoid creating an exam class document from scratch.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I've provided an example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\pointsdroppedatright
\marksnotpoints
\makeatletter
\def\mydroppoints{%
  \leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfill
  (\@points~marks)
  \par
}
% show marks automatically
% \xpretocmd{\endparts}{\mydroppoints}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        \begin{parts}
            \part[4] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \mydroppoints
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### EDIT

According to @David Purton, there is a [better solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459615/201158) which allow line break if there is not enough space.

```
\def\mydroppoints{%
  {\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
   \hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfil(\@points~marks)
      \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}}
```

### Response to the comment

When point is 1, show `1 mark` rather than `1 marks`.

```
\def\mydroppoints{%
  {\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
    \hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfil
    (\@points~mark\expandafter\ifx\@points1\else s\fi)
    \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}
}
```

Comment: Small improvement suggestion: Use `\def\mydroppoints{{\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfil(\@points~marks)\parfillskip=0pt\finalhyphendemerits=0\par}}` which allows the marks to go on the next line if there isn't room for it. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459615/87678

Comment: @DavidPurton I am wondering what is the effect of `\finalhyphendemerits=0` .

Comment: I don't know :). The code is taken from The TeX Book and the only explanation given is the one in the linked question. Many things in The TeX Book are beyond me...

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck I just noticed that this seems to say (1 marks) rather than (1 mark). Can that be fixed?

Comment: @zenofpython sure, fixed.