# Start on the other side

Tags: horizontal-alignment, options

I am searching for a way to start typing on the other side of the page because I want to give a value to some options like:

```
Option A \somecommand 1 point
Option B \somecommand 2 point
Option C \somecommand 3 point
```

Were the points align at the right side of the page, but the options on the left. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Probably `\hfill` is the command you are looking for: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Option A \hfill 1 point
\end{document}`.

Comment: If your options are more than one line, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/550257/201158 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459615/201158 may help